# How to get a Twitter user's handle from a phone number using Twitter API

Tags: twitter

If I have a phone number, and the owner of the number

1. Has a Twitter account
2. Associated his account with the phone number

Can I use the Twitter API to find the account based on the phone number?

UPDATE: What I basically need is a reverse lookup function from a phone number to a Twitter account handle.

Comment: Twitter API search mechanism?

Comment: Although Twitter allows you to bind a mobile number to a Twitter account, it does not make this information available through the API.  I believe you *can* do this with Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not a way to do this, twitter doesn't provide the phone numbers in any form in their api, they also do not let you search based on email address.

this is their user lookup api call
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-users-lookup

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that Twitter would not allow this, since it would be too easy to do a brute-force enumeration of Twitter users who are dumb enough to use SMS to tweet (thereby giving their phone # to Twitter).